# applying difference set operation in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have 23 sentences which i have extracted from text file and 6 most frequent words that are also extracted from the same text file. i have implemented the logic that shows which word occured in which sentence also which word occured with other set of frequent words in which sentences following code and out put illustrates the logic:

```
OccursTogether = cell(length(Out1));
for ii=1:length(Out1)
for jj=ii+1:length(Out1)
OccursTogether{ii,jj} = intersect(Out1{ii},Out1{jj});
end
end
celldisp(OccursTogether)
```

Out1 is 1D array which shows words and in which sentences they occur number wise i have applied setdiff inplace of intersect but didn't get result which i needed. sentences are stored in sentence variable shown as bellow:

```
sentences = regexp(F,'\S.*?[\.\!\?]','match')
char(sentences)
```

following occurstogether shows me 1st word occurs with its self in sentence number 5, 1st word occurs with 2nd word in sentence 5 and 6 and so on..:

```
occurstogether{1,1} = 5
occurstogether{1,2} = 5 6
occurstogether{1,3} = 6 9 20 and so on....
```

what i want to do is to find out where these words don't occur together like as follows:

```
notogether{1,1} = 1 2 3 4 6 7,...23
notogether{1,2} = 1 2 3 4 7,...23
notogether{1,3} = 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 10...22
```

remember these 1,2,3,..23 are the number of sentences in which a pair of words occur together and where they don't occur together the output shows empty {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
occurstogether{1,1} = [5];
occurstogether{1,2} = [5 6];
occurstogether{1,3} = [6 9 20];
N = 23;

result = cellfun(@(x) setdiff(1:N, x), occurstogether, 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

Each cell of `result` will contain a *sorted* vector with *no repetitions*, as per [`setdiff`'s documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html). If you want to change that behaviour see `setdiff`'s options.